# What's the name of a topological space that every open set is clopen?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Is there a special name for a topological space where the condition that every open set is clopen holds?

Comment: Do you have an example of this space, other than a discrete space?

Comment: "totally disconnected" I think

Comment: @Qurultay No: Cantor space is totally disconnected but every co-singleton is open but not closed.

Comment: @JohnDvorak E.g. $X = \{a, b, c, d, e\}$, $\tau = \{ \emptyset, \{a\}, \{b, c, d, e\}, \{b, c\}, \{a, d, e\}, \{d, e\}, \{a, b, c\}, \{a, b, c, d, e\} \}$. Note that the complement of every open set is also open.

Comment: @JohnDvorak They're basically [partitions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3151066/28111).

Comment: Their topology is called [partition topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_topology). Probably you can extend the moniker to the space itself.

Comment: "clopen" ... for closed and open. Why don't you recall the definition of this word (besides, ugly and pedantic) I had never encountered it (though I have done a lot of topology).

Comment: @JeanMarie 'clopen' is widely used, since at least the 60s. You must have had a limited exposure to topology. Maybe you did topology without reading much other people. In any case, be humble and don't use your knowledge or lack of it as a measure for what other people are used to do. The amount of literature is so vast that any single person easily ignores terminology that are widely known.

Comment: All right, consider I have had a limited exposure to topology in english language at that time.  I try to imagine the same thing in French : "ferouvert" (lovely), in German "geschloffen" (very pretty) :)

Comment: @JeanMarie "opgesloten" in Dutch has been heard by puristically minded topologists.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma I surrender ! :)

Comment: @JeanMarie French has ouvert-fermé and German uses abgeschlossene .

Comment: I guess the Stone topology can be an appropriate name to some extent. A non-trivial example which I remembered when I saw the post, is the natural topology on the space of complete types in a structure in Model Theory. Over there, model theorists refer to sets that are clopen and use the Stone topology term.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These spaces are quite rare, and I don't know a name for them. Indeed, they're really just [partitions in disguise](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3151066/28111) and consequently their $T_0$ifications are discrete, so they aren't really "topological" in flavor.

It's worth noting that it's *not* enough to have a base of clopen sets (= zero-dimensional with respect to the small inductive dimension); for example, Cantor space has a base of clopen sets but every co-singleton is open but not closed.