# Union of a open and closed set being closed

Tags: general-topology

Im new to topology, and am trying to prove what conditions results in the union of a closed set with an open set is closed.

Also, just want to check that the union of an open set with it's complement open, and maybe why it is?

Comment: Union of an open set and its complement is the whole space, which is open.

Comment: Do you know when there the union of a closed an open set would be closed? My thought is that they would have be the same set, one open, one closed as the union would then just be the closed set itself

Comment: At least when the open set is contained in the closed set.

Comment: @NiklasArppe could you expand on that?

Comment: Consider the closed set $[0,3]$ and the open set $(1,2)$ in $\mathbb R$ with the usual metric.

Comment: Union of open and closed can be: open $(-2,2)\cup[-1,1]$, closed $[-2,2]\cup (-1,1)$ or neither $[-2,1]\cup (-1,2)$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $C$ be closed set and $U$ be an open set such that $C\cup U$ is closed. Then,
$$C\cup U=\overline{C\cup U}=\overline{C}\cup\overline{U}=C\cup\overline{U}.\tag1$$
Since $\partial U\cap U=\emptyset$, from $(1)$, we deduce that $\partial U=\overline{U}-U\subset C.$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that the union of a closed set with an open set is closed. Since the empty set is closed, its union with every open set is closed. This means that every open set is also closed.

Conversely, if every open set is also closed, the union of a closed set with an open set is the union of a closed set with another closed set, and hence it is also closed.

Thus a characterization of your property is that every open set is also closed, that is, all open sets are clopen.

The topologies with this property are precisely the ones that are derived from partitions of the underlying set. See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3151066).

Comment: Would the downvoter dare to explain his vote?